# Seaborn clustermap with two row_colors

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, seaborn

Quick question, I have a clustermap with variable 'age_range' in row_colors and I would like to add the variable 'education' as a row_color as well. I have the following working code:

```
agerange = df_cor_small.pop("agerange")
lut = dict(zip(agerange.unique(), "rbg"))
row_colors = agerange.map(lut)

ax = sns.clustermap(df_cor_small, cmap='YlGnBu', row_colors=row_colors, figsize=(15,100), cbar_pos=(1.05, .2, .03, .4))
```

outputting this figure:
[image]

(At the moment df_cor_small does not include the variable 'education' but it will once I know how to implement it, so it will be pop-able just like 'agerange')

Any suggestions how I could implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can provide the colors as a data.frame, I think you are providing a list right now. In the example below, I assign black to the 8 colors, 7x20 and 10 to the rows. Did not cluster the rows to show that the assignment is correct:

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(color_codes=True)
import string
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
species = iris.pop("species")
lut = dict(zip(species.unique(), "rbg"))
samples = np.repeat(list(string.ascii_letters[0:8]),20)[:150]
sample_cols = dict(zip(set(samples), sns.color_palette("cubehelix", 8)))

row_colors = pd.DataFrame({'species':species.map(lut),
                          'sample':[sample_cols[i] for i in samples]})
g = sns.clustermap(iris, row_colors=row_colors,row_cluster=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! thanks alot. One small additional question. Age range has 3 levels so RBG works perfect. However, my education variable has 8 levels so the last 5 levels all get assigned white. It there a different rbga argument I can give it to have more colours to my disposal?

Comment: yes, see https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html for palettes. You can pass the color as a tuple into a dataframe, it's not a problem

Comment: I can't tell what is ```education variable```, but as long as you get the dictionary correct, it should work